# How to add an already existing branch in an already existing Android Repository on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git, branch, egit

So I have imported an Android project using the Git import. When I imported it I added all of the Remote branches. But since then some other branches have been added to the project. I am trying to add a branch that was added using GitHub into my Eclipse Git Repository-> Branches->Remote Tracking. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what solved the issue was:

1. On Project in Git Repositories View:
   *rightClick* **Remote->Fetch**
2. On Branches
   *rightClick* **Switch To -> New Branch. . .**
3. **Source:** Select [Branch of interest]
   **Branch name:** [same as remote branch name, this is the local branch name]
4. *click* Configure upstream for push and pull
5. *click* Rebase commits of local branch onto upstream
6. *click* Checkout new branch
7. **Finish**

Comment: Good feedback, similar but more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: Thank you, figured this would help someone down the lines. Thank you again for your help @VonC.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Egit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Tracking_Branches), "Remote tracking branches are created automatically when cloning and fetching from remote repositories."

So after your fetch, you can [click on the `create Branch` icon](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branch_Creation_Dialog) and create a new local branch based on `origin/newReoteBranch` name.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/Egit-3.1-CreateBranchDialog.png]

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help I was able to figure it out.